# How do web analytics platforms (GA for example) calculate unique visitors?

Tags: unique, distinct

Counting distinct visitors is not an easy task.  In web analytics for example, a visitor can visit on Monday and Thursday, but when counting unique visitors over that week, I'd expect to count that visitor only once.

`count (distinct userid)` for 10M visits over a month can't run too fast as aggregations can't be applied (because count distinct is not an "addable" measure).

My question is: How do Google Analytics and other web analytics platforms return unique visitors so fast? I assume statistical estimations are used. What kind? How?

Answer (score 0):

They set a cookie with a reasonable expiration.  If you have the cookie already, you've come back.

Comment: the question is not specifically about cookies, it is more general - how to estimate count distinct for a high cardinality column ?

Comment: "How do Google Analytics and other web analytics platforms return unique visitors so fast?"  They don't count distinct.

Comment: ... rather, they don't do it at reporting time.

Comment: I assume they have a batch operation that pre-calculate everything needed for the report to run fast. 
What is that pre-calculate operation?

Answer (score 0):

See this post for overview of probabilistic approaches http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/probabilistic-structures-web-analytics-data-mining/ that can be used for uniques counting